# Is tangent line same thing as instantaneous velocity?

Tags: calculus

These are the different  questions I regularly see:
Find the tangent line
Find the secant line
Find the average velocity
Find the instantaneous velocity

How are these concepts related and what is the formula to solve each one? Is a tangent line the same as instantaneous velocity and secant line same as average velocity?

I was given these three formulas but am unsure when to use each one in what circumstances, relative to the questions I see above:

$$y-y1 = f'(x1)(x-x1)$$
$$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$$
 $$\lim_{h->0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

In other words, I have a lot of information that I understand abstractly but have no idea how it fits together and I unable to unify my knowledge in a useful way to solve problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tangent line is the direction of instantaneous velocity and the secant line is the direction of the average velocity between the two points.  You still need something to set the speed, the magnitude of the velocity.  For example, if a point is moving uniformly counterclockwise around the unit circle, at the point $(\frac 12,\frac {\sqrt 3}2)$ the direction of the tangent is $(\frac {-\sqrt 3}2,\frac 12)$ and the line is $y=-\sqrt 3 x+\sqrt 3$ but that doesn't give the magnitude of the velocity.

Comment: So under what circumstances would I use the formulas I noted above?

Comment: The first is the equation of the tangent line.  You should be able to match that up with what I did above.  The second is the slope of the secant from $a$ to $b$.  The third is the slope of the tangent line.  It gets you (if you use $x1$) the slope you need in the first.

Comment: @RossMillikan A line -- may it be a tangent line or some other -- is per se no direction but a set of points instead. In your answer you refer to a velocity vector of a curve $J\to \boldsymbol R$, which is beyond the scope of the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks mate! This leaves me with more questions though, namely:

1)Is there any instance where you would have f(x+h) - f(x)/h
 without the limit?<

2)Why is the equation of a tangent line useful?

3)When I get the equation of a tangent line, should I expand it by multiplying f'(x1)(x-x1)?

4)What if I want only the instantaneous velocity and not tangent